# Is answering your own question "Best Practice"?

Tags: discussion

Specifically this question "[What is a Sangha? Do you have to be a Buddhist to join a Sangha?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5834/what-is-a-sangha-does-it-necessary-have-to-be-buddhist-in-sangha)"

The Questioner seems to answer himself a few minutes after asking the question. I feel that this could lead to a conflict of interest in the integrity of this site.

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your own question is fine, and considered well within "best practices" as far as I know. The problem will more be in the content of the question or the answer. If the question is opinion-based, for example, or overly-broad, then it should be flagged, regardless, of course, of whether the questioner answers it themselves or not.

Answer (score 0):

"Doing that is OK" is the normal SE policy.

But on *this* site I think that was overridden by the consensus/voting on [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1785/254) to the meta-topic titled, "May I share my research, by posting questions on this site and self-answering them?".

Sometimes, it will happen: when you don't know the answer, you post a question, nobody answers, you do the research, now you can answer your own question ... but (to avoid flooding the site with such topics) this shouldn't happen more often than maybe a couple of times per person per year.