# Can I post like this topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

See in this topic:

[What are timeframe were pali canons, included commentaries done, especially Mahavihara-Theravada?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/what-are-timeframe-were-pali-canons-included-commentaries-done-especially-maha)

Answer (score 1):

Did you intend to post it in order to answer this question: [Which suttas in the Pali canon are relatively early or late?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/18894/254)

It looks relevant as an answer to that question, and I would welcome it there, if you posted it as an answer.

Or did you intend to post it as a new question? If so can you be more precise about what question you're asking? Currently it looks like you're not asking a question, instead you're answering a question (i.e. you're asking "What timeframe?" and answering that question yourself).

If you're asking a question that you want other people to answer, can you be more explicit about what question you're asking? Are you just asking whether they agree with everything you posted, possibly trying to start a discussion?

Usually on this site we prefer it if you ask questions for other people to answer (and answer questions which other people have asked).

See [FAQ index (summary of site policies)](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2106/254) especially including [May I share my research, by posting questions on this site and self-answering them?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254) -- generally we prefer that you don't post questions only in order to answer them yourself.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't mind about topic combination. But I think a smaller scope topic should put inside a biger scope topic. I decide to begin that new topic, because of topic title's scope. If I post on a smaller scope topic, it will not make sense to reference that topic in the future. The example: the author ask about a,b,c but he has know only a and c, so his topic title has only a,b. But the answer must has c, too. Then when I reference to c in that topic's answer, the title will not make sense.