# "Please stop posting rhetorical questions" valid arguments for wrongdoing?

Tags: discussion

Those in charge, feeling in charge or wishing to assist for better or own, as beneficial seen, interests, or that of others,

Obvious not pleased by question, no pleased by answer, a moderator in aversion, having been given power, deleted both [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/34087/doning-beloved-a-favor-or-ordain), just as a sample.

Case question:

> **Doing beloved a favor or ordain (leave them)?**
>
> There might be accrue doubts like: "Should I strive for the holy life an highest liberation or do those a favor whom I owe much gratitude?" often to trace, last seen here.
>
> What is wise to advice, what would those firm in faith and wise advice?
>
> *(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, entertainment and akusala deeds, but as a share of merits and to continue such for release)

How does such bias ever fit to the site owners interest and policy?

How does such ever fit to the teachings of the Buddha?

Not to speak of the fact that what ever question and answer will always be just rhetoric for those not capable to trace the essence in them.

How can such ever be valid justified?

Is a moderator with possible strong [traumatic problems](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/34078/11235) in regard of shave heads fit to moderate a Dhamma page or might it be more of harm for him and others, since first treatment for with traumatic issues is to avoid touch.

Perceiving the urgency:

> [Kula Sutta: On Families](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.255.than_en.html)
>
> "In every case where a family cannot hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons. Which four? They don't look for things that are lost. They don't repair things that have gotten old. They are immoderate in consuming food and drink. They place a woman or man of no virtue or principles in the position of authority. In every case where a family cannot hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons.
>
> "In every case where a family can hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons. Which four? They look for things that are lost. They repair things that have gotten old. They are moderate in consuming food and drink. They place a virtuous, principled woman or man in the position of authority. In every case where a family can hold onto its great wealth for long, it is for one or another of these four reasons."

Feel free to take it as a opportunity to straighten right view or to nourish wrong views for less benefit. For liberation or staying caught or increase of bounds in the world.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, entertainment and akusala deeds, but as a share of merits and to continue such for release)*

Answer (score 0):

**How does such bias ever fit to the site owners interest and policy?**

It is a policy of this site -- [May I share my research, by posting questions on this site and self-answering them?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254) -- an unusual policy, nevertheless a policy which a majority of the regular users on Meta seemed to prefer.

It's difficult to explain why without being rude (e.g. critical), so I won't try to explain at length again, maybe someone else can.

I know [you may not agree](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/may-i-share-my-research-by-posting-questions-on-this-site-and-self-answering-th#comment4645_1785) with that, even so that *is* the policy (as defined by votes on Meta) -- and it is, as near as I can tell, the wish and expectation of the (often silent) majority or community of users on the site.

I'm not saying it's generally "wrong-doing", only it's not how people want to see the site being used

I see you answered a lot of other people's questions recently -- I hope that helps the people who asked those questions, and anyone who reads the answers with interest, perhaps even helped you.

**Not to speak of the fact that what ever question and answer will always be just rhetoric for those not capable to trace the essence in them.**

It's a technical term -- please read the introduction to  "[rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)":

> A rhetorical question is a figure of speech in the form of a question that is asked to make a point rather than to elicit an answer.[1] Though a rhetorical question does not require a direct answer, in many cases it may be intended to start a discussion ...

In common use I understood it as meaning, 'a question which you intend to answer yourself'.

"Do you know what I mean by that? Well let me tell you, I mean something like this as an example!"

**Is a moderator with possible strong traumatic problems in regard of shave heads fit to moderate a Dhamma page**

Would it be relevant to start by mentioning that "shaved heads" is partly a cultural phenomenon?

I realise that people who look like a Bhikkhu shouldn't be expected to "assault, beat you up, and humiliate" you.

But FYI a "shaved head" doesn't mean that in every country -- isn't always the sign of a Bhikkhu. As a youth, in England I learned to avoid (or to expect to be bullied or even beaten by) any "gangs" of youths on the street -- and some of those gang members had shaved heads (called "skin heads") as their uniform.

Similarly I can perhaps imagine who Andrei might have been talking about -- not a Bhikkhu at all.

Perhaps you misunderstood his message, too: I read it as saying that a shaved head is an example of a "sign" -- like a skirt might be a sign of a woman, for example -- and that people can irrationally associate signs.

Maybe, I don't know, the example was even meant to emphasise how irrational such an association (or how long-lived some early trauma) might be -- because obviously in the present day and present company a shaved head shouldn't be associated with violence -- as well as an example of a remarkable sign.

Comment: Again, neither the owners intent, SE, not confirm with any standard, and just defense, yet surely well meant and lot of work.

Comment: Yes the policy of this site does contradict SE's standard policy, i.e. [Can I answer my own question?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) So far as I know that's the only policy which this site contradicts. The moderators of other sites were surprised we have this policy. SE's employees have seen we have this policy and haven't objected. The "community" of each site has always been allowed to choose (e.g. via discussion on Meta) what kinds of questions they do and don't want to accept. We keep the more essential policies, e.g. "Q&A instead of chat", "Be nice", "Be welcoming".

Comment: Do it away. Thats just a children defend tool for personal interests. And look at Nyom Chris's retoricl answers at meta and even outside its sometimes reveived sometimes not. Total biased and corrup.

Comment: I'm a bit ambivalent about the policy, even though it was me who suggested it. But a majority of other users and other moderators support it, so I can't just do away with it. My policy has moderator has been to find out what the community wants and help to implement that. I won't "do away with it" on a whim, I guess you'd need "popular support" for a change in policy, and that's not easy to get. I don't even know how to get a bunch of users to converse on Meta or in chat. And it is a "lot of work" to post on Meta.

Comment: "After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!", thats the wise purpose.

Comment: I suppose there are other sites on the internet when people post "rhetorical question" and "discussions" -- it doesn't have to be this site too.

Comment: There is no community here at all. Nyom Chris is actually the only putting work for such into it. The idea is old and pseudo-liberal and he had learned, also that respecting the owners interest is importand.

Comment: Democratic is no more a tool at all in a consumer generation that rejects responsibility.

Comment: Grow is much wiser as to hold a stand, sankhara as own and real.

Comment: After all the site needs questions.People love it and it feeds grow and help.