# What about self-answering questions?

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

This is a poll, so please answer clearly and/or upvote an existing answer:

- Do you have any additional arguments, whether in favour or against?
- Should we keep the current policy, of telling people we'd prefer they *don't* post questions in order to self-answer them?
- Should we keep the current "tacit" policy, of *tolerating* some self-answered questions (for example if they're upvoted), as well as of *allowing* or accepting a moderator's deleting such a topic if the moderator wants to?
- Should we change (or simply undo, vote against), the current site-specific policy, and instead welcome (in general) the self-answering of topics?
- Do we need to reconsider any other policy, related to "what is a 'high quality' question?", and, "Is a 'low quality' question ever closed and if so by whom?"

---

**Introduction**

Bhante Kumāra posted (and answered) [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/39572/254) and that led to [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110085/discussion-on-question-by-kumra-bhikkhu-how-should-one-teach-the-dhamma-to-othe).

In that chat I tried to explain this policy -- [May I share my research, by posting questions on this site and self-answering them?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254)

Ven. Kumāra (and Ruslan) would like to revisit and perhaps reverse that decision.

---

**Reasons for disapproving of self-answered questions**

Some of the reasons I gave in chat were that self-answered topics can  be a vehicle for low-quality or disruptive content, for example:

- Someone can use it to an argument across multiple topics, for example:

  > Question: **Is such-and-such true?** User X said "such-and-such", in topic Y. Are they right?

  > Answer: No! User X is *wrong*, and such-and-such is false! etc.
- Someone can post questions which seem intended to prove that their knowledge is superior:

  - "Asks a question"
  - (Waits for other people to answer...)
  - (Posts an answer): "Thanks for trying, everyone, but here's the correct answer which I was expecting: etc."
- Someone can flood the site with several questions and answers per day.
- It can be used for posting dubious content -- conspiracy theories, pseudoscience, maybe spam-like topics.
- It seemed to me that the community had voted against it -- including in [this topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/170/254) which has answers like:

  > Personally, I find seeded questions irksome; it's generally easy to see that the asker isn't really looking for an answer, so there is no sense of accomplishment in answering. It feels more like a chore, like editing Wikipedia or something.

  ... and,

  > Simply put, the best way for a SE site to answer questions from beginners is for *beginners* to ask them. However, SE sites make for great Q&A sites, not for great reference sites.

  ... as well as in [this topic](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1791/254) where even MathewMartin's answer, which appears to say "yes", also says,

  > Yeah, posting a rhetorical question & answering it is bad business (for this site, fine for a blog/discussion forum tho)

  So it was a clear majority of the users who voted -- 9 users to 3 or something like that -- including all three of the moderators.
- Contrary to SE norms, on this site we have little or no quality control on questions -- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) -- and if a question is closed it's closed by moderators not by users. Because "self-answered" question can be unwelcome -- low-quality and/or disruptive, we discourage them in general to avoid having arguments about why *their* question was OK but *yours* is unwelcome.
- In practice moderators aren't strict in enforcing the rule.

  If a user does it occasionally/rarely, if the question and answer are welcome (up-voted), if it doesn't seem "disruptive", then (so far as I remember) moderators don't delete it, instead it's "tolerated".

  The existence of the rule lets us (moderators) delete things if we don't like it:

  - Usually the community has asked moderators not to judge the "quality" of a post (but this rule allows us to)
  - On this site it tends to be only moderators -- not users -- who will close a question (it takes 5 high-reputation users to vote to close, or only one moderator's vote)
- In my personal experience or memory of other SE sites, self-answered questions are permitted but not very important. They're rare on any main site, and are mostly used for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) topics on Meta.

  The most useful, [most-upvoted topics on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) seem to be all people answering other people's questions, not their own.

---

**Reasons for approving of self-answered questions**

Ven. Kumāra's argument for permitting them includes:

- They're usually allowed on other SE sites -- [Can I answer my own question?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

  > Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer their own questions.

Furthermore (quoting from chat):

- > And I'm also saying trust SE's design to make Buddhism.SE work, because it has proven to work elsewhere. There's no reason it wouldn't work here. And there's no proof that it's not working.
- > I'm believe when people use is like their onw blog, they question will get much downvoted and the person will eventually leave. This is not just a theory. We already have proof of this.

  (Therefore allowing self-answers isn't harmful -- instead simply downvoting is enough to solve the problem and/or make people leave.)
- > Besides, if we want to attract more experts, then openly allow self-answering, because that's an important factor in attracting them. By disallowing it as a policy, or even just to discourage it almost as a rule, the moderators have undermined a major reason why SE is successful elsewhere.
  >
  > Experts who want to share find this an attractive place. We should encourage the useful ones, and shoo away the useless one, instead of shooing away all of them.

I suspect that users in favour of this change, and/or who may want to post self-answered questions, include Ven. Kumāra (who's proposing this change), [Ruslan](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2467/254), perhaps other (current or former) users including [Theravada](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254) and [Lowbrow](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1790/254), and perhaps [Samana Johann](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2347/254).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, what I like to do is to post a question sincerely i.e. where I do not know the answer to the question.

Then I choose the best answer to the question, and this must come from others.

However, I may later post an answer based on useful information that I discovered AFTER posting the question, in which case, I will never accept my own answer.

The reason for this is that I think this is very useful information that should not go unposted, and would add value to the question.

My example for this is [Was the Abhidhamma taught by the Buddha?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/39442/471).

Comment: Yes that's currently/already welcome -- that was the reason why, and the (only) extent to which, [MatthewMartin's answer voted "yes"](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1791/254).

Comment: I think this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm strongly opposed to giving green light to quasi-questions posted with the sole intent to share an opinion, an unsolicited teaching, rambling, philosophical musings etc.

If someone can enumerate and define scenarios when self-answering is not utilized in order to take advantage of Buddhism SE platform to push unsolicited info at the audience, and develop some sort of guidelines for telling them apart, we may be able to find a better compromise than today's black-n-white policy.

> I believe when people use it like their own blog, their question will get downvoted and the person will eventually leave.

Regarding the above, my experience from being on this site since 2014 is exactly the opposite. Instead of getting downvoted out of sight, low-quality content -- including the preaching/rambling-style questions and answers -- attract other similar low-quality questions, answers, and comments, which creates a self-supporting cyclical tendency that eventually crowds out good quality content, discouraging serious users and pushing them to leave.

Comment: [Ven. Kumāra's example](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39573/254) of a self-answered question was not down-voted, seemed to be orthodox, well-explained, a conventional format (a sutta which previous users have seen occasion to post more than once). Self-answered questions are by definition "unsolicited", aren't they. Apart from "unsolicited" are there another criteria to distinguish low-quality posts? For example whether they're "[Disruptive behavior](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)" (i.e. "other users tend to react poorly, etc.")?

Comment: To me, Kumara Bhikkhu's post was off-putting *exactly* because of its unsolicited nature. Imagine if I started posting unsolicited Mahayana teachings copy/pasting verbatim quotes from Chogyam Trungpa's lectures - wouldn't that be off-putting to many users? My guess is that some users would quietly leave and some would start posting their own content in response to mine and the whole thing would snowball.

Comment: The only exception I would make is when the OP posts a sincere question, is not satisfied with any answer, then subsequently does his/her own research and posts a satisfactory answer. Even in this category moderators would have to remain vigilant to censor unsolicited advice disguised as "better answer".

Comment: Right. Another scenario/use-case I imagined was, someone might post a summary here each time they posted a new Dhamma talk on YouTube or a blog -- in theory the number of posts could explode. And I know you're sensitive about one user's not pushing other topics off the front/active page of questions, "flooding" the site (though other sites have to learn to deal with many questions per day). But if it's so that self-answered == unsolicited == off-putting, there's not much wiggle-room, not much room for discussion or compromise. Would rate-limiting help, e.g. a guideline of 2 per week per user?

Comment: Maybe I should ask on meta.se how do other sites welcome self-answered questions without their being treating as spam (i.e. "unsolicited" albeit not commercial). On a big site like SO I guess it's taken for granted that nobody will read everything that's posted, and if you don't like an on-topic post (self-answered or otherwise) then downvote it or just shouldn't read it -- and there's some ability to ignore tags -- and that might work, or be the best they can do, for huge sites.

Comment: Sure, you can ask around. I'm thinking, maybe a combo of rate-limiting and reputation-thresholding? Unfair but reasonable in a way... [FromScore, ToScore, UnsolicitedPostsWeeklyAllowance] 

Comment: So you're not against rate-limiting. I wonder whether Ven. Kumāra would accept it as reasonable safety valve, or whether it's just another unwanted rule. I wonder what else we could do; if this were Discourse (which it isn't) they could be posted as a new Category; but SE only supports two categories, i.e. main and Meta.

Comment: `... the whole thing would snowball` And not sure whether snowballing would be a bug or a feature, I guess it depends on what you want of a site and the quality of the snow. Increased volume would mean more to moderate, other sites expect the users (not the moderators) to moderate content -- to vote-to-close and so on -- which I'd say they haven't been doing here.

Comment: Come to think of it, your last comment has some logic to it.

Comment: Aggressive Staggering by Reputation would prevent the worst part of the problem IMO. Like, until you have a ~1000 points (maybe even 5000) your Unsolicited Allowance should be zero.

Comment: Historically the two users of this site who posted the most numerous rhetorical or pedagogical questions, which weren't entirely "well-received", and which we've tried to stop because they seemed to be flooding the site and poorly-asked, and/or argumentative+disruptive, were both high-reputation "trusted" users (over 4,000) -- so I'm not sure that (reputation) is a very useful correlation. Conversely some of the most expert (and reputable) people in the world are not the most avid users of this site, and I'm not sure we ought to discriminate against them on that basis.

Comment: What might you think of this as a policy: "if users don't want to vote-to-close, then why should we (moderators) try to do it?"? Maybe we should stick to moderating users instead of content, including moderating users for reasons like, "**consistently low quality questions over time** *We've noticed that you've asked many questions, a large number of which were not well received by other members of our community. Specifically, many of your questions were downvoted and closed* etc."

Comment: That would imply that we moderators should [refrain from voting-to-close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350383/139866) if there's any doubt (though we can down-vote and comment).

Comment: To me the fact that the two worst offenders were in 4000s just means we need to set the barrier even higher, maybe to 10k. The world-class experts on Buddhism with no reputation on this site would need to prove their expertise *and* commitment to this community *and* fitness to share in this democratic format where they are not the central figure on stage - before they can post unsolicited advice.

Comment: I don't think moderating users is a good idea, too ad-hominem and too much generalization for my taste. Moderating content seems more objective and easier to substantiate: "this phrase is not acceptable" vs "you've been a bad boy lately" .  Also, I don't think we can solely rely on community self-moderating here - not active enough.

Comment: `too ad-hominem and too much generalization for my taste` That's why our job is to do it "as little as possible" IMO -- but when there's "*a dark storm cloud of moderator flags that seems to follow this user around wherever they go* etc." then that's our job. Moderating a user is not very nice, and I see the appeal of (I tended to prefer) a systematic/formal rule which tries to ensure that users can only act cooperatively, and avoid opportunities for inter-user friction, but (perhaps the cost of that rule is too high, preventing additional helpful self-answered content and happy users).

Comment: Oh yes of course -- if we "moderate a user" then we talk about content: what they posted (if it was rude) and/or how it was received (downvoted and closed by other users). I meant that the user community should be the arbiters of what content is welcome, and to that extent we shouldn't try to moderate content.

Comment: `To me the fact that the two worst offenders were in 4000s just means we need to set the barrier even higher, maybe to 10k.` One I'm thinking of was 30k, isn't that so? An infeasibly high bar -- which goes to show that a user's being an avid/prolific user of the site, and knowledgeable, doesn't necessarily imply their questions or their "unsolicited advice" are necessarily well-received (welcomed) -- so instead (if we allow it all) we might need to allow it on a case by case basis, perhaps depending on the community's reaction to it (instead of e.g. a reputation-based privilege).

Comment: If you wanted to make it privilege-based I might suggest that [500 or 750](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) would be a threshold -- that's the level at which people are deemed to know the community well enough to vote-to-close.

Comment: Alright, your arguments against the reputation-boundary are sound. And yet I'm not convinced we should greenlight a random newbie getting on the proverbial soap box just because they are a Bhikkhu channeling EBT or a Vajrayogini spontaneously speaking rhyming Dharma poems, or anything else. How are we to decide who is allowed to get on the box and who's not? I suppose the main issue here is community self-moderation or rather the lack thereof, right?

Comment: The answers to this -- [How do sites moderate self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350585/139866) --  might be kind of conclusive/instructive, what do you think? In summary IMO that's saying, 1) We should allow it in principle 2) It probably won't be too bad in fact 3) Ensure the OP posts good questions (which other people might want to answer or see answered) not just self-answers, if not then users (not necessarily moderators) can vote-to-close the question. 4) Users (subject matter experts) can downvote and vote-to-delete bad answers too.

Comment: 5) If a user is disruptive -- hostile, flooding the site, often posting unwelcome questions -- then we should have a word. 6) In our case (small site) if users can't or won't collectively muster the necessary quorum of 5 votes-to-close or v-to-delete, IMO we moderators could amplify them (by casting a super-vote after just a few people vote) -- but that's not a decision we need to make preemptively (by banning self-answering), nor is deciding whether any given content is good a decision we should make alone (though I think we should intervene if a post seemed hostile or anything like that).

Comment: So I propose we reverse our policy at least experimentally; and ask interested users to use their voting privileges (up and down, close, and delete) on the main site.

Comment: Do any of those people moderate religious Q&A sites? Anyway, I'm OK with trying it out.

Comment: OTOH I was wrong to say "I recommend" -- it's "they recommend" -- I am still reluctant, for reasons I already wrote, and your reasons, and [Yuttadhammo's](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/171/254) i.e. *"seeded questions are irksome" and [Shog9's](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/172/254). [Unrul3r's self-answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1874/254) showed more research effort than [Ven. Kumara's](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39573/254) because it aggregates material from several references (not copying and giving some IMO obvious comments on one sutta).

Comment: If I say "I'm reluctant" that means I find it hard to imagine this feature being used well. OTOH the fact that I don't imagine I'm able to post good self-answered topics myself doesn't mean that other people -- people who are relatively more expert -- might not, so maybe I shouldn't put a blanket ban on it preemptively (not that I do, instead I might I warn new people against it as you did, but then tolerate it unless it seems disruptive).

Comment: No I don't think "any of those people moderate religious Q&A sites". We could ask those sites too -- via their Metas or chat -- or ask their mods on Temperance. Do want to do that?

Comment: It's encouraged on Christianity: [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/42437) and [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1567/42437), which encourage the practice.

Comment: as long if something doesn't have awful content, or is egregiously self aggrandaising or pejorative to others or to Buddhism etc(noticed a recent edit that had alleviated something along those lines), then if it's simply somewhat off or too biased or assertive, then maybe just make a mild comment or two to the question, but nothing drastic or notnice, & readers can see that as they consider the question!

Comment: `Anyway, I'm OK with trying it out` I hope this is alright then (albeit wordy again) -- [Proposal: Self-answering questions is welcome](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2500/254)

Comment: Proposal looks good I cast my vote

Answer (score 1):

- "Asks a question"
- (Waits for other people to answer...)
- (Posts an answer): "Thanks for trying, everyone, but here's the correct answer which I was expecting: etc."

I think this kind of answer should be edited so that it neither extolls some nor disparages others by asserting one's correctness.

I know some people post answers like this to regular questions and i am pretty sure i've flagged some as abusive. I've been annoyed and posted answers like "how on earth can people think that..." i think even that is unnecessary and id be rightly censored.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I *didn't* feel I had to moderate this kind of behaviour and/or expression i.e. "conceit" -- that it didn't happen or that I could cheerfully ignore it -- but I fear it does annoy some users, and/or leads to arguments (annoyance, people leaving), and a few people seem to do it for whatever reason, so I get involved in trying to moderate it. Even if people don't say it explicitly (comparing people, disparaging others), I'm mindful of what Ven. Yuttadhammo said (above) about "seeded questions".

Comment: So, editing it (as you suggest) is a start -- but I'm not sure it's sufficient -- even if it's edited (not explicit), if other users don't answer a question because it's just a "chore" and "irksome" and "no sense of accomplishment" then I fear that the quality-per-topic might drop, and engagement (enthusiasm) may drop, and the community splinter e.g. into those who do and those who don't want to engage with the questions or assignments from that OP.

Comment: IMO there's a certain symmetry to keeping people separate (i.e. you can ask a question if you want someone else's answer, or answer someone else's question if you want to and can).

Comment: There is a whole 'nother, separate topic -- which is that we have e.g. a lot of questions about for example [tag:anatta] and so on, which aren't clearly organised. If someone wanted to write reference material (instead of answering other people's questions), perhaps there ought to be some "FAQs" on this site. But that's more work (time and effort) than I want to put into this myself at the moment; and that kind of scribing (re-reading and editing, synthesising existing answers) might not be the sort of work that an "expert" would want to do (they might prefer to write their own answer).

Comment: Anyway I'll take your/this answer as a vote to continue my current policy, i.e. that an answer must not explicitly disparage another user or their answer. Your answer is also a vote for a new policy, that authors should or must not extol themselves or assert their own correctness. Though on the subject of at least implicitly asserting one's own correctness, note that references which "back up" an answer are welcome [but are not required](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/254).

Comment: I think answering one's own question should be done as if one was able to answer anonymously and if community doesn't like the content they can downvote it like any other answer. Ideally imo there should be no special dynamic between the question and the answer. I am not a fan of playing games with the questioneer nor completing or handing out assignments.

Comment: The case of basically mere posting of Q/A from the sutta requires little to no effort. However i think these can be good as a wiki of sorts, so i wouldn't mind this content either. especially if the Q/A derived from the sutta is complemented by other discourses or relevant information then these become very good imo.

Comment: This is very similar to people posting sutta excerpts on facebook as i see it but here done in a q/a format. I personally don't mind it as it is good that people read the discourses and maybe the answers complement eachother. Furthermore if there was a big database of this type of content and it was well organized & searchable, that would be quite valuable.

Comment: To summarize think this type of content is basically an effort to repost the entirety of the Q/A contained in the Suttapitaka to BSE in accessible format for easy reference.

Comment: I assume it was more targeted, i.e. that sutta was chosen to be especially relevant to the readers of this site. That intention itself makes self-answering questions slightly at odds with [this popular policy](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/254): "*In general, unless you actually are the questioner's teacher, don't assume a teacher's mantle.*" (even if the suttas and his commentary may be good advice, as well as well-intentioned of course -- plus it is good/better to have some actual teachers on the site).

Comment: Looking through topics which previously mentioned [AN 5.159](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%225.159%22) I found this -- [Which early canonical references help one find a skillful teacher?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1874/254), posted when the site was started. That was popular and you might like it because "the Q/A derived from the sutta is complemented by other discourses". That's something Piya Tan does too somewhat, i.e. cross-reference suttas.

Comment: Of course [some people](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/172/254) don't think that sites should be for copy-and-pasting references and for emulating Wikipedia (Shog9 was was of the SE "community moderators") -- IMO what makes this site especially useful is that it's interactive, responsive, personalised -- because otherwise there's lots of reference material on the 'net already, and the content of this site isn't especially well organised or structured for reference.

Comment: I guess the most compelling arguments were "the moderators have undermined a major reason why SE is successful elsewhere" (*is that so...?*) and "self-answering is an important factor in attracting them" (*if you say so...!*). Another thing he said is we can "shoo away the useless one" (*I'm not sure how that would work*).

Comment: I made a similar question recently (among others) about how to discern true Dhamma and it's not something i am proud of. I feel that if i kept posting such questions it is somewhat dishonest because the motive for asking was muddied and i just think this may or may not be what the site was intended for. It's not organic content so to speak, it's just otherwise fabricated content even tho indestinguishable from a genuine question from one seeking knowledge on a subject.

Comment: In regards to the most compelling arguments, i think the argument for allowing inorganic questions is "why not?". I think self answering is the norm elsewhere and opposition has to prove or at least make a good case for their position. I see little to no harm in fabricated questions aimed at documenting knowledge / creating content for future reference other than that it may not be what the site was intended for.

Comment: OTOH i think among the primary objectives of the site is for it's content to appear in search results of google and for people to find good answers, maybe it's an overly cynical take on it but these inorganic questions and self answering is conducive to accomplishing that goal.

Comment: It's also impossible to police people's intention and some self answering is certainly "good". Ie if i have a real difficult question solving a controversy and get no good answers on my question, if i am then able to solve it otherwise i think the community would want me to share the answer

Comment: I think asking whilst knowing the answer beforehand is different in that it does not benefit the questioneer in the same way but it still benefits the community and the would-be questioneers.

Comment: `among the primary objectives of the site is for its content to appear in search results of google for people to find good answers` One of the ways in which it's meant to host good answers is that there may be *several* answers -- "*2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top*." Even if a self-answered question isn't actively disruptive, the community's being unenthusiastic about questions posted with that intent (what you call inorganic questions) might be not ideal.

Comment: Part of my fear is that on this site we don't have much mechanism to "shoo away" low-quality content -- and inorganic content doesn't have the "checks and balances" of ("you can choose the topic by asking the question, but then you can't answer as well"). Also if most users don't want to engage with inorganic content then that's unfortunate too. If it *were* only a matter of high-quality contributions by experts then, sure, what's the harm, why not I suppose. In theory the number of posts might explode, e.g. anytime someone gives a Dhamma talk they might post a summary of it on this site.

Comment: When I'm voting against that it's because I'm afraid of the worst case scenarios -- as a moderator I might be more intimately familiar with or fearful of those worst case scenarios are than other users. Perhaps it's telling that all 3 current moderators voted "no".

Comment: I think the 'users might not want to answer the inorganic questions' is a scary thing but is unlikely to happen because we don't have  evidence suggesting that it will be the case and we have some evidence suggesting otherwise. I think as long as the content is good as in it is beneficial to site's visitors then nothing bad will happen. This being a Beta the community can experiment imo. I don't address the other concerns because i either don't think it is a concern andor i don't quite understand what you are saying.

Comment: Also if you think we lack mechanisms to shoo away a certain type of unwanted answers the mrchanisms can be developed if the community shares your sentiment.

Comment: I could name a few users on this site whose questions I wouldn't want to answer myself -- in my experience, trying to answer their questions feels like attempting and being told I've failed an exam -- so I don't answer but I read the question with a kind of dread of what will happen to any unfortunate new users who naively make a good-faith effort to answer, given that the OP already has their own "right answer" in mind, an agenda to push. That's *one* of the worst-case scenarios, imo.

Comment: I am pretty sure i know one person like this and i don't engage him either. Ive been likewise baselessly accused of cherry-picking in my answers by people who seem to have an agenda. I think these people end up disparaging others and can be forced to just give answers without disparaging and accusing others of wrong-doing by giving them suspensions.

Comment: These are outlier characters and their behavior is so abnormal that it should be easily shut down due to violation of existant rules or new rules can be created to moderate that behavior imo. There is no need to make broad restrictions which affect well-behaved users, what is needed is clearly defining the unwanted type of behavior and for the community being united in rejecting it.

Comment: Rules should be in place to protect the well-behaved people and to restrain those who are otjerwise. This was the principle on which vinaya was developed and it's very good imo. Well-behaved people will behave within the norm but if the rules infringe on otherwise good behavior it is a problem and the rule is then too broad and thus the community ends up handicapping itself.

Comment: Also if there is a restriction on good behavior then you get generally well behaved people rebelling against it, disrespecting the rule, being annoyed and making a commotion.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is 3 situation:

1. One does not know the answer and later after finding something useful hence adds a late answer which is acceptable.
2. One has an answer in mind. Unless one is a pure novice one will have some answer, in many cases it is the level of confidence and depths in the knowledge is what changes. In this case, the answer should be posted with the question so others do not was time digging up the same information or trying to answer at the same depth. Also, others can share answers where their angle differs from the given answer. This can also be verifying if one's position is right or if one has missed any angle. Not being able to share what one has got would mean one gets answers on what one already knows or may not be at the depth one is seeking and wasting everyone's time. E.g. one has a Sutrantha answer but not the full Abhidhamma angle not sharing this means someone may also give a Sutrantha answer wasting his and your time. Providing and answer reduces the burden on others to the amount of facts they have to research to complete or different angle to the question.
3. Questions to test others might not resonate well with uses and these are the ones which need to be discouraged.

Comment: Right. So your #1 agrees with ruben2020's answer. Your #2 agrees with existing policy i.e. ask a detailed  sincere question about what you don't know, show your research about what you know already in the question (but don't self answer). And #3 agrees with existing policy i.e. especially don't self-answer in order to test people and to claim that your own answer is superior.

Comment: In #2 I mean **answer your own question immediately (do self answer immediately or without delay)** when you ask the question **if you have an answer** so others can give something ***1) different 2) additional*** and not wast time answering what you know. **Your answer is just another answer which can get votes by its merit.**

Comment: #3 is ***not giving an answer immediately and when someone gives an answer*** saying **"this is a wrong answer and this is the answer I have been expecting"**.

Comment: Oh -- when you said "the answer should be posted with the question" I thought you means "as part of the question" -- a bit like [in this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3420/254) where I posted some references and partial answers as part of the question. The way I read your #2 example, your actual question is really/only about the Abhidhamma, and that is the question which only other people can answer.

Comment: Re: #2 - If you post as part of the questions the voting mechanism cannot work for one's partial answer. One's own answer serves as and references on which others can give something additional or another angle. Say my answer is the Sutta angle some sone else can give another answer with the Abhidhamma angle. If my answer is based on say X, Y sutta someone else can give another saying Z Sutta also mentions this.

Comment: So you're in favour of posting self-answered questions so that your answers can be up- or down-voted.

Comment: Answers are sorted by votes. So what should be at the top is what is the best. So if the subsequent answers are mediocre one's answer should be at the top. If other answers are better they should Bubble to the top. For this to work properly though we need a reasonably knowledgeable community. 

What if you have a good question with bad assumptions about what the answer is. If it is the body of the question others cannot signal this by voting other answer over this.

Comment: Thats an excellent point: some answers may actually be incorrect(based on well known concepts such as The Four Noble Truths) yet presented flamboyantly etc readers may infer that it is correct cf a plainer answer(or perhaps boringly written) which might go unnoticed or even misunderstood yet is fairly accurate! Also, the further a question or answer is from central concepts, the more expertise and insight may be needed to discern its accuracy! good stuff is assumed to rise up, but may not. Or a question may seem abrasively worded, but more because of an Askers language ability!

Comment: And if very good & insightful answer was misunderstood & received downvotes , the Answerer might delete it because they wouldnt want people to be mislead and infer that is wasn't correct! Whether a question was selfanswered wouldn't affect that! so maybe it's good to try consider questions & answers individually rather than to try aggregate them into groups to either be unallowed or allowed. If some selfanswered questions seemed getting out of hand, maybe just ask them to ease up. And if selfanswered questions are open to information, they could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> What about self-answering questions?

I vote to keep the policy as it is now.

Removing it would allow anyone (teachers, self-appointed experts, preachers etc.) to post their own answers. It could become messy and lead to arguments and discussions on the site which we have tried before. It takes a huge toll on moderator resources.

IMO it's better to keep the policy as it is now and do as @Ruben has mentioned in his [*answer*](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/what-about-self-answering-questions/2483#2483).

Comment: You might want to [vote "no" here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2502/254) in that case. The first time we voted, all 3 moderators as well as other users voted against it. But with Ven. Kumāra's saying now that the policy is unattractive to experts, plus the fact that self-answered questions are allowed on every other SE site, I thought we should at least reconsider (even if our answer is still officially "no maybe better not").

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for the info. I see the issue and think it's fine that the topic gets brought up.