# Is it permissible to answer your own question by synthesizing answers from others?

Tags: discussion

According to the rules of *this* site [as I understand it,](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1784/may-i-share-my-research-by-posting-questions-on-this-site-and-self-answering-th/1785#1785) we are encouraged not to post questions and then answer ourselves. However, I wonder if it is permissible to provide an answer which is a synthesis of other's answers.

Specifically, in [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/are-the-skandhas-reborn-from-moment-to-moment) I think there are many great parts to each answer, but find that no one answer is sufficient. I'm wondering it is permissible or advised to provide my own answer which is effectively a synthesis of the other answers with some minor tweaks along the way.

The original question was [motivated by a request for elaboration](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/37243/13375) on another answer and I think the best help would be a synthesis of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be welcome.

As I remember it the policy was that own-answers to a question are especially permitted if they're based on research which you hadn't already done when you asked the question -- synthesising answers would certainly qualify for that -- or if someone does it very rarely.

The purpose was to keep the (collaborative) Q&A nature of the site -- discourage people using it as their personal blog -- and ensure that the topic is one which users other than the OP might want to see answered.

Answer (score -1):

> According to the rules of this site as I understand it, we are encouraged not to post questions and then answer ourselves.

Actually it isn't a rule but even against the sites philosophy and a product of mood many years ago, maintained as "reality" by some.

There is hardly any Q&A community which seeks not for possible all ways to get an answer and who if not a questioner, after a good research, could possible provide a better in certain cases.

Of course it's not easy to give up a perception especially if a lot of wrong doing was in connection with it.

PS: Good householder is welcome to give his own answer to his question here as well, like moderators usually do as well and foremost.

*[Note that this isn't given trade exchange, stacks or to maintain unskillful perceptions in ways that they are hold for real but for liberation for sticking to unwise and harmful]*